# Reuse hadoop connection with hadoop -fs shell

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

I have a shell script with a lot of hadoop fs commands like:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal a b
hadoop fs -chmod 755 /a
hadoop fs -chown hdfs /c
...
```

Every time command is executed it creates a new connection which takes some time. Is that possible (not using java api) to stop wasting time on closing/opening connection every time for such kind of script?

Comment: There is no specific shell for hadoop, So we cannot use same connection.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the performance issue is more to do with spinning up a new JVM than with the connection itself.  What I do is write small python programs (with the requests or urllib2 modules) that use the WEBHDFS REST API and it is much faster than scripting around hadoop fs.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html